# CSS: <h2> is longer in IE7 than in FF

Tags: css, browser

The string "Fernando Salgado Alonso" is much longer in IE7 than in FF.

Why? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I removed most of your question, since the "page" you show didn't include the string you're referring to or an `<h2>`...

Comment: it probably has to do with the font styling Have you applied a reset to the font? you may want to set the font and use pixels for size to confirm this.

Why do you need to change this pixel equivalent is not usually required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because different browsers have slightly different default css for displaying unstyled content.

You need to use a css reset and apply your own rules on top of that. That way you will be sure that it displays the same on all browsers.

Some well know resets are:

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
- http://code.google.com/p/blueprintcss/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset